# How to commit changes made in exported working copy from SVN repo

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I exported a working copy from svn repo using tortoise svn, made changes to it, now I am confused about how to commit these changes
Do I have to import whole project again which is 600 MB in size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]Exported (see 1 on picture) from repository tree is **unversioned** set, not related to source repository anymore in any way
In order to change|commit you must to use Checkout (see 2 on picture), which created Working Copy, which have direct relation with source repository

You have to read ABC and re-done your work with good, brain-powered style (because you have zero knowledge for fixing current half-broken state)

1. Empty checkout to existing folder with files
2. Update with infinity depth (and resolving conflicts on update)
3. Commit